# Knockoutjs nested foreach on a nested object

Tags: javascript, object, knockout.js

I'm new to KnockoutJs and can't seem to figure this out. I have an array of objects called "weeks" and each object has an array of objects called "week". How can I do a foreach on each week. Here is what I tried so far but getting nowhere.

model:

```
var Model = {
  weeks: ko.observableArray([
{"week":[ {day:'01', total:'109'},  {date:'05', total:'250'} ]},
{"week":[ {date:'02', total:'102'}, {date:'05', total:'255'} ]}             
  ])
};

ko.applyBindings(Model);
```

view:

```
<section class="dates" data-bind="foreach: weeks">
    <article data-bind="foreach: $data.week">
      <span class="day" data-bind="text: day"></span>                   
      <span class="dayTotal" data-bind="text: total"></span>                    
    </article>
</section>
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: If you use the same property names for every object: so replace date to day then your code is working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Grn7M/

Comment: I think you have a typo : first object refers a day property and the others have a date property. So  replace day  by date.

Comment: Thanks, what a shame I'm debugging a typo for 2 hours

Comment: And note that your current setup has the array of weeks observed but not the array within the 'week' array nor the properties within that. So, depending on what you're actually trying to do, you're pretty limited here.

Comment: If you don't want to use any element for your upper foreach ('Weeks') , you can use ko binding like 
<!-- ko foreach: weeks --> 
...your code
<!-- /ko  -->

Answer (score 1):

Using the same fix that @nemesv did with your view model, here is how you could loop through each week (as per your original question). Here's a fiddle showing it, http://jsfiddle.net/b7gpP/

```
function loopWeeks() {
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(Model.weeks(), function (weeks) {
        for (var i = 0; i < weeks.week.length; i++) {
            console.log(weeks.week[i]); // here you have access to one of your week objects

            // set value of a day
            weeks.week[i].day = "4";

            // get value of a day
            var day = weeks.week[i].day;

        }
    });
}
```

It's slightly ugly, at least in terms of KO; but your individual weeks aren't observables. If you intended for them to be observables, let me know and I'll alter the post.